# Where/how to run sails new <project>?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, sails.js

I know this sounds dumb but I just installed sails.js with:

```
npm install sails -g
```

and the next step is to run:

```
sails new myProject
```

Now I've tried this at 1) the Windows command line, 2) Under npm and 3) under node.  Nothing works.  BTW, node, npm and express are all working.

So how do I get started?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777), correct the package name in the title, and remove references to your level of experience; then describe the failure _specifically_.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I've adjusted the title, sorry about that.  I don't know how I can be more specific. I've described the issue.  What else?

Comment: Thanks for editing; the issue is that "nothing works" is too vague for anyone to help you. What are the error messages, ...? Also, it's not clear to me what trying "under npm" and "under node" means.

Comment: I would describe which step is failing `npm install sails -g` and / or `sails new myProject` . You must also include your version of Node, Npm, & Windows and also include the console output that describes the error you are receiving.

Comment: OIC.  OK.  I've been using node, npm and express for a couple of weeks just trying to learn.  All of that works.  Now I've installed sails.  AFAICS the install succeeded.

Comment: OIC.  OK.  I've been using node, npm and express for a couple of weeks just trying to learn.  All of that works.  Now I've installed sails.  AFAICS the install succeeded. Now, from a Windows command window, I run npm sails new myProject.  All I get is the "usage npm <command> and all the usual npm help info.  <Continued>

Comment: Next, I run node in the same command window and, from the node prompt I run the same sails command.  All I get from that is three dots and nothing else happens.  Finally I exit node with two <ctrl>c's  to get back to the win command line and again run the sails command (sails new myProject).  From that I get the the message that the sails command doesn't exist.  Hope that clarifies a bit.  Thanks!  (Sorry about all the comments but I keep running out of room).

Comment: @user5464745: Please incorporate your comments  directly into your question, then delete the comments. Also, in the future, please add a specific problem description _right away_, and add a tag that reflects your platform (OS), if it is relevant (I've done it for you here). 
Also, it is better to be less verbose, so as to make it easier for others to get to the salient information.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow! Feedback can seem harsh, but it's because we have high standards. In the end we're here to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sails` is a *CLI* meant to be run *directly* from your terminal (Command Prompt in Windows) - do *not* try to invoke it via `npm` or `node`.

Since you installed `sails` globally (`-g`), the CLI should be installed in the following location:

```
%APPDATA%\npm\sails.CMD
```

e.g., at `C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\sails.CMD`

For you to be able to invoke this batch file (`*.CMD`) by its name from anywhere (i.e, as `sails`), folder `%APPDATA%\npm` (translated to a *literal* path) must be present in your system's `%PATH%` variable - the Node.js installation should have ensured that; execute `path` in a console window and examine the output to verify that this folder is listed.

Comment: Even though I'd installed sales and was pretty sure the installation succeeded, it turned out I did not have a sails.cfg file in ...\AppData\Roaming\npm.  I did have a sails directory at that location which led me to believe things were OK.

Now I've re-installed sails and the sails.cmd command is there and ...\AppData\Roaming\npm is in my path! <continued>

Comment: BUT even so, I have to run sails (i.e. sails.cmd) from that directory.  From other directories I still get "'sales' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Any idea why the path isn't working.  I do have a very long path. I wonder if there's a limit.

Thanks

Comment: I just cut a bunch of old stuff from my path and now things seem to be working properly.  Thanks!

Comment: @user5464745 Thanks; re max. length of the `%PATH%` variable: apparently, it's 2047 chars. pre-W7, and 4095 chars. on W7 or higher - for the gory details, see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/limitation-to-the-length-of-the-system-path-variable